# OpenGL not drawing textured and non-textured quads simultaneously

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to draw a textured quad, then on top of that a black rectangle which has no texture. I use `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before I draw the textured quad and `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before I draw the non-textured quad, but My textured quad only appears for a split second and then I'm left with my clear color filling the entire screen and only the non-textured quad showing up. Why is this happening?

P.S: I call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` before doing any render work, not in between the render methods so that shouldn't be the problem I think

Also, I can only see the non-textured quad even if I draw the textured quad on top of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Turns out I didn't set a color before doing the textured quad so whenever i changed the color of the other quad this color is changing as well, so setting the color before binding the texture worked.